# why 117.5\ 19.5 gives me 5 in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I need to convert some old vb.net project to c# and get confused with some behaviour differences for the `\` operator.

For example, I can understand `7 \ 2 = 3` (as it takes the integer part of the result). But why `117.5 \ 19.5 = 5?`

In my calculator 117.5 / 9 =6.025.., so above should give me 6 other than 5?

Comment: The \ operator asks for integer division. So the operands have to be converted to integer first, then the result of the division is truncated to integer.  So you, probably, get 118 \ 20 = 5.  You can't be complete sure if a floating point fraction of .5 gets rounded up or down, the processor must approximate it if the number is not a sum of powers of 2.

Comment: It's integer division so it doesn't really sense using it on floating point numbers

Comment: @HansPassant - isn't `.5` always exactly representable? Since it's `2^-1`?

Comment: You are right.  Mostly, this kind of question happens when the user looks at a calculated value in the debugger.  A number with a non-fractional part that is too large is another corner case.

Answer (score 3):

The reverse solidus operator in Visual Basic .NET is for Integer division. Since both the divisor and the dividend must be integral types (and I'm assuming that you have Option Strict Off), the values are implicitly being converted to an Integer. So `117.5 \ 19.5` turns into `118 \ 20`.

My first suggestion would be to turn Option Strict On to avoid the implicit conversions. My second suggestion would be to use the forward solidus operator which is for floating point division since you're dividing to floating numbers anyways: `Dim foo As Double = 117.5 / 19.5`

Answer (score 0):

According to [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/operators-and-expressions/arithmetic-operators) both the divisor and the dividend must be integral types, and will be converted to them prior to the operation.